# Why does "System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs.Clicks" always return 0?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have the following event handler for a `NotifyIcon`, and `e.Clicks` always returns `0` when the event is fired.  Why?  What am I overlooking?

```
Private Sub NotifyIcon1_MouseClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon1.MouseClick
    Debug.Print(e.Clicks) 'prints 0
End Sub
```

Comment: @abatishchev -- explain your edit.

Comment: What does return 0? Clicks or Print? Clicks. What for do you need Print then?